# Probability inequality involving partition

Tags: probability, inequality

I've got a partition $E_1, E_2, \dots, E_n$ and an event $A$ with $P(A)>0$. I'm trying to prove (or find a counterexample) that:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \left[(P(A|E_k)-P(A))\cdot P(A\wedge E_k) \right] \ge 0$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider $e_k=P(E_k)$ be probability weights and $x_k=P(A|E_k)$.

The equality is basically (up to factor of $n$):
$$\langle x^2 \rangle - \langle x\rangle^2 = \mathrm{Var}\,x$$

i.e. this is non-negative (as a variance).